# javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I am using Spring 3.1.2 , Jboss 6.4 and jdk 1.7.80.
While login I am getting error:
javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out.
i used following code,but not worked.

```
    <bean id="contextSourceTargetApp" 
         class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
                <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
                       <map>
                              <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout"                        value="5000" />          
                        </map>  
                 </property>
     </bean>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your LDAP configuration too.

Comment: I Am using "org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource"